# How to use semaphores with Shared Memory

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory, semaphore

I wrote two simple processes - client and server (in c++ - LINUX) that share the same memory, one that writes to it and the other only reads from it.
(took the code from this website:

> http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html#SECTION002730000000000000000

***The problem:*** 
I need to make sure that the second process doesn't read from a certain line/address while the other process is writing to it (but it can read from other lines/addresses).

for example, if the "server" is writing to lines 10-15, the "client" cannot access those lines, but it can read from the rest of the lines.

I know that I need to use ***semaphores***, but I don't know how to combine it with shared memory.
Any example code/ help on how to use semaphores?

*Note: I used SystemV IPC and not POSIX.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This 16 page document should help you understand and implement semaphores: http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/23-Concurrency-Examples.pdf